# Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset B \subset X$. Show that if $A$ is dense in $B$, then $A$ is dense in $\overline{B}$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset B \subset X$. Show that if $A$ is dense in $B$, then $A$ is dense in $\overline{B}$.

The subspace $A$ is dense in $\overline{B}$ if $\overline{A} = \overline{B}$.

To show equality I'm thinking of doing both inclusions.

So first if $x \in \overline{A}$, then by definition $O_x \cap A \ne \emptyset$ for all neighborhoods of $x$, $O_x$ open in $A$.

But since $A \subset B$, then $O_x=U \cap A$ for some $U$ open in $B$. Therefore $$x \in O_x \cap A = (U \cap A) \cap A = U \cap A \subset B \cap A = A \subset \overline{B}$$ so $x \in \overline{B}$.

Convresely if $x \in \overline{B}$, then $U_x \cap B \ne \emptyset$ for any $U_x$ open in $B$. However $B = \overline{A}$ since $A$ is dense in $B$ so $$x \in U_x \cap B = U_x \cap \overline{A}$$ which implies that $x \in \overline{A}$.

Is this correct? I'm taking into account the density of $A$ in $B$, but I don't know if I'm making a silly mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

**Easier Way:**
Since $A$ is dense in $B$ so $\overline A=B$.

Taking closure on both sides: $\overline{(\overline A)}=\overline  B$

This gives $\overline A=\overline B$ (Since $\overline{(\overline A)}=\overline A).$

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me. However, it is much simpler to prove that $\overline A\subset\overline B$ using the fact that $A\subset B\implies\overline A\subset\overline B$.

Comment: Yeah I figured that I'm overworking in the first inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is dense in $B$ iff $B \subseteq \overline{A}$. It follows that $\overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A}$ so $A$ is dense in $\overline{B}$.